# Uniform boundedness Schrödinger operator eigenfunctions with Dirichlet conditions

Tags: reference-request, schrodinger-operators

I would like to ask a question with possibly a reference. If we have a Schrödinger operator $-\Delta+V$ on an interval $[0,L]$ with $V$ continous and Dirichlet conditions, can we state that the eigenfunctions of such operator are uniformly bounded, i.e. there exists $M>0$ such that the eigenfunctions $\{\phi_n\}_n$ satisfy

\begin{equation*} \sup_n \lvert\lvert \phi_n \rvert\rvert_\infty\leq M \end{equation*}
?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this follows because asymptotically, as $|z|\to\infty$, the solutions of $-y''+Vy=zy$ look like those of the free equation $V\equiv 0$, and the eigenfunctions of $-y''=zy$, $\phi_n=(2/(L\pi ) )^{1/2}\sin n\pi x/L$, are uniformly bounded.

In fact, they are uniformly bounded not just in $n$, but also in the potential $V$ as long as we impose a uniform bound on $\|V\|_1$.

(I'm assuming here that you normalize your eigenfunctions as usual, $\|\phi_n\|_2=1$, and then you are asking about $\|\phi_n\|_{\infty}$.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your assumptions are correct. I understand what you mean and numerical simulations point that way but I could not manage to find precise proof of that. Could you suggest any reference?

Comment: The book by Poschel and Trubowitz discusses asymptotics in some detail (though with an $L^2$ assumption on $V$, which isn't necessary; you can adapt the proofs if required) and it's what I usually quote when I use these things, but there are many other references, so keep searching if you don't like this (Marchenko's book is another option).

Comment: @Christian Remling Christian, do you know examples where $\sup_n \|\phi_n\|_\infty$  really depends on $\|V\|_1$ ($V \geq 0$)?

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune: I think one way of doing this is to take $V=0$ on $(0,a)$ and $V=N\to\infty$ on $(a,L)$. In the limit $N\to\infty$, this will simulate a Dirichlet boundary condition at $x=a$, and if $a$ is small, then $\|\phi_n\|_{\infty}/\|\phi_n\|_2$ will become large.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Thank you, right!